# Understanding the Lifespan of Properties Added by Middleware in Node.js Express

Tags: node.js, backend, request-response

In my Node.js Express application, I'm using middleware like **`multer`** for handling file uploads and **`cookieParser()`** for managing cookies. These middleware functions typically add properties to the request and response objects, such as **`req.file`** for multer or **`req.cookies`** for cookieParser.My question is, how long do these properties persist in the request and response objects? If I add a custom property to the request or response object in a middleware function, will that property be available in every subsequent request that comes to the server?

```
// Middleware function
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.customProperty = 'some value';
  next();
});

// Route handler
app.get('/example', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.customProperty); // Will this always be available?
  res.send('Response');
});
```

i want to ensure that any custom properties I add to the request or response object are available throughout the entire request lifecycle and not just for a single request. Could someone clarify how this works and provide some insights into the lifecycle of these properties added by middleware functions? Thanks!